# subst "/dev/ttyPS1" to \""/dev/ttyPS1\"" in makefile

Tags: makefile

I'm trying to perform this substitution without any success with the following,

```
a="/dev/ttyPS1"
b=$(patsubst \"%\",\\\"\"%\\"\",$(a))  
c=$(subst \",\\\"\",$(a))
$(info $(a) $(b) $(c))
```

Output :

```
$ make
"/dev/ttyPS1" "/dev/ttyPS1"   "/dev/ttyPS1"
```

Desired Output :

```
$ make
"/dev/ttyPS1" \""/dev/ttyPS1\""   \""/dev/ttyPS1\""
```

I must be doing something dumb with the escape sequences since it doesn't appear to change at all... I don't have any preference on how I get there (patsubst, subst, or other). Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: You don't need to escape quotes with backslashes in make syntax.  Quotes are not special to make.  Thus your subst of `\"` never matches because there's no two-character string `\"` in the string `"/dev/ttyPS1"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to escape quotes with backslashes in make syntax: quotes are not special to make. Thus your subst of `\"` never matches because there's no two-character string `\"` in the string `"/dev/ttyPS1"`.

Try:

```
a = "/dev/ttyPS1"
b = $(patsubst "%",\""%"\",$(a))  
c = $(subst ",\"",$(a))

$(info $(a) $(b) $(c))
```